# How do I make a program that recognizes that a certain prefix is repeated in a String?

Tags: java

I have to create a program that recognizes prefix repetition, for example, if the string selected by the user was "coconut", and "2" was the int value, the program would print "co is a repeated prefix in coconut". If "3" was the int value, then, upon running, "coc is NOT a repeated prefix in coconut" would be printed.

I've tried utilizing substrings to return the characters of the persons choosing, however, from there, I can't figure out how to make a Boolean or if statement to accomplish what I want.

Comment: You will need to use `substring` multiple times in a loop (as a sliding window) and count matches until the first mismatch.

Comment: What's the specific issue? You know the substring to look for, and you can find out where in a string the substring was found (used to continue looking).

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Initialize boolean isRepeated
    boolean isRepeated = false;
    
    //Initialize scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Obtain user input for word
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    String word = input.nextLine();
    
    //Obtain user input for number
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    
    //Set prefix as substring of word
    String prefix = word.substring(0, num);
    
    //Iterate across the word starting after the prefix
    //Make sure i+num <= length of word to prevent 
    //an array out of bounds exception
    for (int i = num; i + num <= word.length(); i++){
        
        //If the substring starting at i and ending before i+num
        //equals the prefix, set isRepeated to true and break loop
        if (word.substring(i, i+num).equals(prefix)){
            isRepeated = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    //Print whether the prefix was repeated or not
    System.out.println(prefix + (isRepeated ? " is repeated" : " is not repeated"));
```